# How quickly should I try to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

It seems clear to me that when I'm in a community with "hard questions" (ie. ones that have clear answer) it makes sense to me that I should accept the best and fastest answer.

However, for a community with more "soft questions" (ie. ones that do not have clear answers) I am wondering if there are some guidelines to follow, or some common practice, for how quickly to accept answers.

Comment: Whenever you feel like it. Don't accept answers to please someone.

Comment: Btw: accept rate was removed. Nobody cares about it anymore (or, at least, shouldn't care).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *don't* have to accept an answer, and you shouldn't feel pressured to do so.

If an answer doesn't obviously stand out from the lot, then simply don't accept any answer.